# OSX alternative to dlmopen

Tags: c++, c, macos

dlmopen is missing on OSX I'm porting a Linux app to OSX and Im using it intensively, is there any other alternative to dlmopen on Mac?

Comment: The `dlmopen` function seems to be a SunOS/Solaris specific function.

Comment: Which `lmid` value is the current code using?